# Cassandra:Executing multiple DDL statements in cql file

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I would like to execute over hundred of user-defined-type statements. These statements are encapsulated in a .cql file.

While executing .cql file everytime for new cases, I find that many of the statements within it gets skipped.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is any performance issues of executing 100s of statements composed in .cql file

Note: I am executing .cql files on behalf of a Python script via `os.system` method

Comment: Why you expect that there should be performance problems, especially for DDLs?

Answer (score 0):

The performance of executing 100's of DDL statements via code (or cql file/cqlsh) is proportional to the number of nodes in the cluster. In a distributed system like Cassandra all nodes have to agree for the schema change and more the number of nodes, more the time it takes for schema agreement.

There is essentially a timeout value **maxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds** which determines how long coordinator node will wait before replying back to client. Typically case for schema deployment is one or two tables and the default value for this parm works just fine.

Since in the special case of multiple DDL executed at once via code/cqlsh; its better to increase the value for maxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds say to 20sec. Its going to a take a little longer for the schema deployment, but it will make sure the deployment succeeds.

[Java reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/metadata/)
[Python reference](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html)